# Installing another audio card for system sound recording

Tags: audio, pci, audio-recording, front-panel, on-board-peripheral

I need to record my screen. Everything works fine except I am getting bad quality sound (onboard sound card) in any screen recorder software. Installed newest drivers. I have tried everything. [Camstudio](http://camstudio.org/) can't even detect recording line for speakers.

```
Motherboard Name - Gigabyte GA-945PL-S3
Realtek ALC888 @ Intel 82801GB ICH7 - High Definition Audio Controller [A-1] - PCI
Operating system - Windows XP Professional
```

This onboard card Is very good, because it has 4 rear `Speaker outputs`, one rear `Microphone` jack and one rear `Line In` jack. Front panel has microphone input and speaker output. I can change the behauvier of these jacks. For example I can use the *Realtek HD Audio Manager* to set all connectors to output sound or input sound, or just manage each connector. That's why it is a good onboard card. But I need to make a christmas video with recording my screen, sound and microphone except my card has bad a quality of audio recording. Also the card can suppress background noise (can listen to TV that is 1 meter far from microphone and talk with friends, no problems).

I have this old but still working fine audio card: *Creative AudioPCI 9918*.

[image: This is not my image, but this is same PCB]

I was using this card to record my system sound on the old computer, but now it's just lying around. So my idea is to use this card for recording sound and use my front panel for mic and headphone. Will this setup work or I just need to think of something else without loosing front panel?

Comment: I am not understanding completely. Can you clarify what you mean by "record my screen"? Also, the onboard audio should be much better than the old card. With exception to recording the microphone, music and video are combined via software, not the sound card. Check your settings to make sure your microphone is set up properly.

Comment: @CharlieRB Everything is fine, double checked. Just the `Stereo Mix` is recording with bad quality. I need to record my system sound, speach I can record other day.

Comment: That looks .. seriously oldschool

Comment: possible duplicate of [using onboard sound card with dedicated soundcard](http://superuser.com/questions/100997/using-onboard-sound-card-with-dedicated-soundcard)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with Camstudio related to HD audio. Here is a link to several suggested fixes [on Camstudio's forum](http://camstudio.org/forum/discussion/288/realtek-hd-audio-does-not-work). Be aware there is a lot of reading and some are computer brand specific.